# rotation of object using matrix multplication

Tags: matrix, rotation, multiplication

I have written code on how to Rotate an object without using matrix in C++ and it works perfectly. I am not able to come up with the logic of how to rotate the same object using matrix multiplication. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create the rotation matrix - the relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) shows how to do this for each axis, then you multiply them together to combine them.

Then, multiply the position vector of each vertex in your object by that matrix to get a new set of position vectors.